# Conditional Expectation with two dependent conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

$X$ and $Z$ are two independent Normal random variables and $k$ is a constant. I am interested in the following conditional expected value
$$\mathbb{E}(X|X < k, X +Z > k).$$

My concern is how to take into account the second condition, which involves another random variable. Note that, since both $X$ and $Z$ are Normal random variables, $X +Z$ is also a Normal random variable, which depends on $X$.

Comment: Are we assuming here that $X$ and $Z$ have standard normal distribution (i.e. mean zero, variance one), or arbitrary mean and variance?

Comment: $Z$ and $X$ are not necessarily standard Normal distributions and have arbitrary mean and variance.

Comment: But they are independent, there is a difference. independence ($F$ is C.D.F. here, but it is correct for other statistics too, for example P.D.F. $p_{X,Z}(x,z)$):  $F_{X,Z}(x,z)=F_X(x)F_Z(z)$, now $X$ and $Z$ can have whatever mean or variance they want. If they were not independent, then $F_{X,Z}(x,z)\neq F_X(x)F_Z(z)$. For Gaussian, independence is equivalent to uncorrelatedness, which means $\mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X))(Z-\mathbb{E}(Z)))=0$ .

Comment: The reasoning provided by [epimorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/74908/epimorphic) made it clear. You are right actually and I was wrong, Consider $X,Z\sim \mathcal{U}(-1,1)$. The expectations are $\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]=\int_{-1}^{0}xf_X(x|x<0)dx=-\frac{1}{2}$. While $\mathbb{E}(X|X<0,X+Z>0)=\frac{\int_{-1}^{0}x\times\frac{1}{2}dx\int_{-x}^{1}\frac{1}{2}dz}{\frac{1}{8}}=-\frac{1}{3}$ which are obviously unequal. I withdraw my answer then. The conditions change the region of integration which transcends the independence (which only appears in the form of the density functions).

Answer (score 0):

Does this figure help?  (I assume statistical independence of $X$ and $Y$.)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the figure (especially, in a parametric way).

Comment: It is a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution where the red area is for $x<k$ and $x+y>k$.

Comment: Then how would you use this figure to calculate the expectation?

Comment: Integrate over the red region.